# Replace group with spaces

Tags: regex

I need to hide part of the string. Hide all before some ending part.

It easy to implement by regexp like this:

```
replace("123-134-04", ".(?=.*-)", " ")
```

replace any symbol if future part of string contains "-".
So result is:

```
"       -04"
```

It is important to keep spaces.

But, I can't use lookahead or lookbehind.
I can catch the group before ending part, but how to replace this for right number of spaces?
Or maybe some other ways to resolve this with regex?

Tnanks in advance!

Comment: What language/tool are you using for this and why can't you use lookahead?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 with Saxon implementation. Yeah, I can write helper templates or functions, but regex is preffered.

Comment: Specification of xpath contains no lookahead in regex, and this is really not working =)

Comment: This is not possible in a single regex operation with a regex engine that doesn't support lookahead assertions.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of to be replaced characters does not differ too much, and you have a means to match the part to be preserved, you could run through a series of search and replace:

```
replace("12-14-04",             "^.{5}(-[^-]+)$",  "     \1")
replace("123-134-04",           "^.{7}(-[^-]+)$",  "       \1")
replace("adfasd-adf-da7474-04", "^.{17}(-[^-]+)$", "                 \1")
```

Or you do:

- split the string at the position, where the to be preserved part begins,
- run the `replace("ALL OF THIS SHOULD BECOME BLANKS", ".", " ")` on the first part, and
- join them up again.